# Not able to parse Date in unix time format

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, linechart, react-d3

i am very new to coding and stucked somewhere while making LineTooltip using react-d3 library.
i am getting time unix time format like:1450274696000 in json and need to parse it and show d,m in x-axis
i am using this function:

```
   var parseDate = d3.time.format("%B %d, %Y");
   var x = function(d) {
      return parseDate(new Date(d.index))
     }
```

and calling linetooltip as

```
 <LineTooltip width= {1200} height= {400} interpolate = {"cardinal"} data= {chartData} chartSeries= {chartSeries} x= {x} xScale={xScale} />
```

Please help me out!...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a tip: this is *not* unix time format.

Comment: very sorry for that

Comment: but can you help me out with this milliseconds

Comment: What exactly is your question? because the code works.

Comment: i am getting error:DOMPropertyOperations.js:143 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,17.142857142…".

Comment: my sample json:
var chartData = [
{"indoortemprature":25.3,"index":1450274696000,"age":39}
,
{"indoortemprature":27.5,"index":1450297319000,"age":38}
,
{"indoortemprature":24.5,"index":1450318604528,"age":34}
,
{"indoortemprature":25.6,"index":1450336738000,"age":12}
,
{"indoortemprature":25.7,"index":1450354911425,"age":26}
]

Comment: You'll have to share all your react-d3 code here, because that snippet in your question is working. It gives me "December 17, 2015".

Answer (score 0):

> no neeed to pasrse data as milliseconds can be directly converted to Date object, like this

```
 var x = function(d) {
 return new Date(d.index)
  }
```